# Disallow routes in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

If I have routes like `/info/page1` and `/info/page2`, but route `/info` doesn't exist, if I write `Disallow: /info` in robots.txt, robot will go to `/info/page1` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you disallow "/info", you cannot to go on /info/*